# How to set selected date on Jquery Calendar Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am using the calendar app on a page that has a set date. I have it so when you click on the calendar, whatever is in the input that has the date, gets changed to the date you clicked on.
When you load into the page I want whatever date that is in the input to be what the calendar is set to. Thanks.
LINK TO PLUGIN - https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Simple-jQuery-Calendar-Date-Picker-Plugin-DCalendar.html

```
var pageDate = "4/04/2018";

<input class="date">





    $('.date').val(pageDate);
    // Make above date the selected date
// Code below is for setting input to date you select. Currently works.
    $('.box').dcalendarpicker({
                format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
            }).on('datechanged', function(e) {
                console.log('Date change');
                var d = e.date;
                selectedDate = moment(d, 'MM-DD-YYYY');
                var theDate = selectedDate._i;
                $('.date').val(theDate);
                var weekdayLongform = selectedDate.format("dddd, MMMM");
                var dateLongform = selectedDate.format(" D");
                var yearLongform = selectedDate.format(" YYYY");
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the date as the value of the input (in the same format specified in the plugin initialization). That will do the trick.

```
<!-- value specifid as mm-dd-yyyy -->
<input class="date" value="03-11-2018">
```

Comment: Okay, so setting the inputs value attribute, sets the calendars selected date?

Comment: @Will according to the plugin, yes, if you set the value of the input in the same date format.

Comment: Hmm.  Doesn't seem to work. Setting that value to a correctly formatted date then having $('.theInput').dcalendar(); doesn't change anything..

Comment: According to the source JS, the plugin will get the value from the input, in the defined format; but, you need to bind the plugin to the input: `$('.date').dcalendarpicker(...options);`; maybe you could bind the click to `.date` to `.box` so when you click on `.box` the date picker will open.